# не подключаются стили css

Tags: css, slider

добрый день, 
у меня проблема следующая - шаблонный код background-slider

http://turisto-travel.az/slovenia.php - ссылка

этот слайдер не отображается, хотя на страницах других стран все показывает..

не могу понять в чем тут дело..

заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: по любому проблемы с путями до js , css

Comment: ну так в консоле как раз все красное из-за путей)

Comment: Там 449-я (`Retry With`) ошибка. Пути стало быть ни при чём. Озадачьте того, кто там у Вас серверной частью занимается.

Comment: хостер говорит, что с его стороны все работает..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать абсолютные пути к файлам стилей:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: тогда почему на страницах других стран, все показывает?

http://turisto-travel.az/denmark.php 
http://turisto-travel.az/maldives.php

там тот же самый стиль и шаблон слайдера, только фотки меняются..

Comment: Jugin, пробовал, не помогло..

Elena Semenchenko, вы о чем?

Comment: @Chupacabra, что "Вы о чем?" Все о том же у Вас не правильно прописаны пути к скриптам и стилям по отношению к файлу! Такие пути стоит и для других стран прописать `/css/bootstrap.min.css`!